# How to convert list to cv::UMat?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have the list, this list gets from dlib detector:

```
dets = detector(frame, 0)
dets = [list(rect_to_bb(dets[0]))]
print(dets)
[[277, 294, 150, 149]]
```

How I can convert this list to Umat ?

```
faces = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
print(faces)
[[259 264 182 182]]
```

The exception, when I use the list

```
    _, landmarks = facemark.fit(gray, dets)
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'faces'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert it to `UMat`? Because of the error message?  If so, then this is most likely a X-Y problem. Often this message comes up when resolution of parameter types fails. It first tries to convert to `Mat` and on second attempt it tries `UMat`, and only the last failure produces an error (so it can be rather misleading). I wouldn't be surprised if all you need is to make `dets` a simple numpy array instead of list. Hard to say exactly as a proper [mcve] is missing.

Comment: Seconding Dan's comment.  I got the same error for the `points` argument of `cv2.fillConvexPoly()` (I was passing a numpy array).  In my case the solution was simply to set the dtype of the array to `np.int32`, so no need to actually convert to `UMat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dets = cv2.UMat(np.array(dets, dtype=np.uint8))
```

look at [link](https://answers.opencv.org/question/187401/obtaining-opencv-umat-shape-in-python/)